# Moment of inertia around two axes

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, moment-of-inertia

In the [this](http://web.njit.edu/~kappraff/chapter19.pdf) chapter of an online pdf we are given an equation for the deflection of a beam:
$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{\overline{M}}{E I}$$
where $E$ is the modulus of elasticity, $\overline{M}$ is the moment as function of $x$ and $I$ is the moment of inertia. It works nicely for a beam with one free end as the beam would be rotating around a single axis. However when they get to the worked example with both ends fixed they leave the moment of inertia uncalulated (left just as $I$). I am wondering how one would calculate the moment of inertia for such a beam. Is it even defined?

Comment: Note that the $I$ in $T=I\,\omega$ is completely different from the $I$ in $M = E\,I y''$. Apparently this Prof. in the department of Mathematics in NJIT does not have an engineering background.

Comment: A flexed beam is not rotating about a fixed axis. The end if the beam is not rotating and the further away you go the more rotation you have, in a non linear fashion. A rotation as defined in dynamics implies deflection simply proportional to distance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [**area moment of inertia**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_area_moments_of_inertia) for beams is defined from the geometry of the beam cross section and not from the end conditions. It is defined as $I_{xx} = \int (y^2+z^2)\,{\rm d}A$ and has units of `LENGTH`<sup>`4`</sup>. The $x$ and $y$ values are usually displacements from the [neutral axis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutral_axis) which lies along the [centroid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_centroids).

The same equation holds regardless of the end conditions. The end conditions define the constants of integration when getting $y(x)$.

### Example

Rectangular beam with elasticity $E$ and length $L$ is loaded in the middle by force $P$, and fixed at the ends.

1. Look up in the lists of area moments $I_{xx} = \frac{b^2+h^2}{12}$ where $b$ is base of rectangle cross section and $h$ the height.
2. The internal moment a distance $x$ from one of the ends (I call *A*) is $M(x)=M_A - x\,A_y$ with $A_y$ the vertical reaction force, and $M_A$ the reaction moment at *A*. Force and moment exist in order to enforce the no displacement and no slope at *A* constraints.
3. The deflection shape is $$ y(x)  =C_0 + C_1 x + \int \int \frac{M(x)}{E I}\,{\rm d}x\,{\rm d}x = C_0 + C_1 x +\frac{x^2 \left(3 M_A + x\,A_y \right)}{6 E I} $$
4. The end conditions at *A* are $y(0)=0$ and $y'(0)=0$ (with $y'$ denoting slope) yielding $C_0=0$ and $C_1=0$  $$ y(x) = \frac{x^2 \left(3 M_A + x\,A_y \right)}{6 E I}$$
5. In the middle of the beam the slope must be zero (due to symmetry) and thus $y'(\frac{L}{2})=0$ yielding $$M_A = \frac{A_y L}{4}$$.
6. The total reaction force must be equal to the applied load and thus $A_y=\frac{P}{2}$
7. The deflection shape is now
   $$ \boxed{ y(x) = \frac{P\,x^2 \left(3 L-4 x\right)}{48\;E\,I} }$$

Answer (score 0):

*I am not an expert in this and since I couldn't comment I'll just leave what I have to say here.*

Look up the Parallel Axis Theorem:

$I_A = I_{COM} + Mh^2$

Where $I_A$ is the moment of interia at any point, $A$, of the object, $M$ is the mass of the object and $h$ is the distance from the COM (Centre of Mass) to the point $A$. $I_{COM}$ is the moment of intertia around the centre of mass.

[image]
Ignore $d$ from the diagram; I just wanted to show you the typical set up of the problem.

Comment: You are confusing mass moment of inertia, with area moment of inertia. The first is used in dynamics, and the second in statics.

Comment: Are you saying that because of the diagram? As in: it should not be a 3D object. I should have found a better example. Or maybe the Parallel Axis Theorem isn't the correct method for this question?

Comment: Yes, but with area, not mass. $I_A = I_C + A\,d^2$ where $A$ is the cross section area and $I_C$ the area moment about the centroid.